# Dynamic field binding inside a repeat control

Tags: xpages

I have a strange thing, I'm using dynamic field binding in a custom control.

The field binding is created like this.

- XPage (Datasource "document" is placed here)

  - Custom Control (String passed in)
      (to get errors if there are any)

    - Repeat (CompositeData is passed to a bean that returns the strings for Rows,columns)

      - Repeat (repeat 1 variable used for Columns)

        - Custom Control (fieldname is passed in)

field binding is done like this
**#{document[compositeData.fieldName]}**

The problem is that when I save the XPage I get an error in the messages control

Document has been saved by another user - Save created a new document as a response to that modified document.

And all fields are cleared.

Any ideas how to debug this or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

The "Document has been saved by another user" error is only tip of the iceberg - there are some really strange problems with reapeats that repeats fields that are bound and repeatControls property is set to false. The decoding part of xpages lifecycle cannot handle it properly - the controls will be losing data. You should use repeatControls set to true as Martin suggests.

"Repeat control variable doesn't exists" is probably caused by the property that removes repeats set to true. You can solve this by either changing it to false or by adding additional data context that will keep repeated value.

And finally for this to have add/remove functionality You can use Dynamic Content Control and show(null) hack to rebuild the repeat content.

To manage this complexity better I would advise You to stop using document data source and start creating some managed beans.

If You will follow my suggestions I guarantee that You will get the functionality You are looking for as I have few apps that works great and have this kind of complex data editors in them.

Comment: What do you mean with this ?
show(null) hack to rebuild the repeat content

Comment: Dynamic Content Control (dcc) can be foreced to rebuild its content by calling getComponent('dcc').show(null) - the show method takes name of facet as a param but when You pass null it will simply rebuild its children (including repeats)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it'll help you, but I pass both the document datasource and the field name as parameters to a DynamicField control, and use it like this:

```
compositeData.dataSource[compositeData.fieldName]
```

The type of the datasource is com.ibm.xsp.model.DataSource, it's listed as dataInterface under Data Sources.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have repeatControls="true" set for the repeat control?

Comment: No I haven't for two reasons number one if I do I get an error saying that the inner repeat control variable doesn't exists. And the second reason is that I would like to be able to do a partial refresh and add fields.

Comment: I was thinking about this, because I have had similar trouble couple of weeks ago [see my blog post.](http://jinoch.cz/dynamic-binding-fields-bug)
Imagine you have hardcoded customControl, the binding is there "from designer". The binding works because it is done early in JSF lifecycle. And the same way it works if you set repeatControls="true".

Comment: Thanks, but something else is wrong. Error handling with repeat controls need some work from IBM I think.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've got the datasource defined multiple times on the XPage (plus custom controls). Either that or the save button has save="true" but the code saves the document back-end, or code in multiple places saves the same document. I've used the same method of passing the datasource down to the custom control, but that may just be because that was what I saw on a blog.

Comment: Actually no extra datasource, button is not a submit button the property save on the button is blank. the only thing on the button is "datasourcename".save() + a full refresh